# Flutter - There is a problem when distributing the app to the Google Play console but there is no problem in the app bundle test, emulator test

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, bundle

There is no problem in the app bundle test, the emulator test, or the test using a mobile phone device, but there is a problem when distributing the app to the Google Play console.

When the app is downloaded, tflite's model cannot be loaded, so a circle progress indicator appears.

I think there is a crash between the tflite package and the url launcher package.

Here's a link to the Google Play app that's getting the error.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.act99.primi

It is difficult to explain in words, so I upload a link to GitHub.

https://github.com/act99/error_1

tflite load error -> [error_1/lib/screens/two_choose_screens], [error_1/lib/screens/more_choose_screens]

url launcher error -> [error_1/lib/screens/two_photo_screens], [error_1/lib/screens/more_photo_screens]

Please help me.

Comment: Did you rename two_choose_screens.dart to more_choose_screens.dart ? Try flutter invalidate cache and restart and then create a new app bundle?

Comment: Hi. "two_choose_screens.dart" and more_choose_screens.dart are different code. / I tried flutter invalidate cache(flutter clean) before creating a new app bundle. But this problem occurred.

Comment: Try to 'import  url launcher as urll' and 'import tflite as tensor' ? Perhaps they use the same kind of ClassName in their respective library ? But normally the editor should have caught it, are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Hi, @AntoninGAVREL I'm using Android Studio, but there's no error while using it. I would try to 'import url launcher as urll' and 'import tflite as tensor' and I will distribute the app for testing.